# Did I use trigger properly?

Tags: sql, triggers, transactions

I have a program in C#.  I have no question about the C# code but there is something that bothers me.  I have been using a trigger in some big transactions in my system.  Is it really advisable or good practice to use a trigger in transaction?  I have been researching and found that I should use triggers only in audit trails. But I have no problems when using triggers.  I'm asking this question because I really want to know your opinion so that in the future if it's not advisable then I can avoid using the trigger in a transaction.

Comment: Well, how about showing us what the trigger does, and other related tables, etc.  What is a "big" transaction?  Please go read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ,  and http://sscce.org/

Comment: First of all, SO is not a place for opinions. Its a place for technical facts. Therefore your question can't be answered here, due to policies. *But*, even if it could, you have provided too little information about what your app, your db and the trigger itself.

Comment: In SQL triggers are triggered in dependency of an update, a delete or an insert, all of those operations use a transaction, though it maybe only an implicit one.

Comment: I apologize for asking this in SO but I want to hear the opinions of the other programmer like me which the SO has about my system I can't explain it in detail but now I get the disadvantage maybe I will change my approach and avoid using trigger.

Answer (score 6):

Major drawbacks of using triggers are:

1- Making the whole process slow in large number of transactions

2- Lack/difficulty of control especially for checking the result of the action done by trigger

3- Making your system more difficult to maintain

4- Injection of problems regarding concurrency

Comment: 5 - breaking things like BulkInserts because a large number of people don't know how to use triggers properly anyway

Comment: I apologize for asking this in SO but I want to hear the opinions of the other programmer like me which the SO has about my system I can't explain it in detail but now I get the disadvantage maybe I will change my approach and avoid using trigger.